# How To Make an Android Login App?

Tags: php, android, post, authentication, http-post

I have a task to make an android app that capable to access pages that need to be logged in.
I don't have access to the php code that site use.
this is HTML source of the site:

```
<center>
    <div id="loginWrapper">
        <div id="loginBox">
            <div id="loginBox-head"></div>
            <div id="loginBox-title">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
            <div id="loginBox-body">
                <form id="form-login" action="https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pModule=bG9naW4=&pSub=bG9naW4=&pAct=cHJvY2Nlc3M=" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="aid_username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" onBlur="clearPasswordField();" />
                    <label for="aid_password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" />
                    <label> </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                    <hr />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="loginBox-foot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

I see that https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pMod ... JvY2Nlc3M= is the way it go if I click Login button.
When I accessed that URL, It responsed that I need to input username and password.
I tried to pass username and password to the URL, so it would be like this: https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pMod ... Fzc3dvcmQ= and it still responsed that I need to input it.
So, I know that it pass username and password by socket parameter.
I tried to use firebug (firefox add-ons) and login it manually and this is the result:

> ```
> POST index.php?pModule=bG9naW4=&pSub=bG9naW4=&pAct=cHJvY2Nlc3M=
> Params
> -----------
> pAct   cHJvY2Nlc3M=
> pModule   bG9naW4=
> pSub   bG9naW4=
>
> Headers
> -------------
> Response Headers
> Server   nginx/0.7.64
> Date   Wed, 14 Dec 2011 19:56:32 GMT
> Content-Type   text/html
> Transfer-Encoding   chunked
> Connection   keep-alive
> X-Powered-By   PHP/4.4.8
> Expires   Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
> Pragma   no-cache
> Location   https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pModule=aG9tZQ==&pSub=aG9tZQ==&pAct=dmlldw==
> Content-Encoding   gzip
> Vary   Accept-Encoding
>
> Request Headers
> Host   xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx
> User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
> Accept   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Language   en-us,en;q=0.5
> Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
> Accept-Charset   ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
> DNT   1
> Connection   keep-alive
> Referer   https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/
> Cookie   PHPSESSID=ecf5337e2f08bf48537da099b90b8a3f
>
> Post
> --------
> Parameters
> password xxxxxx
> username xxxxxx
>
> source
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 31
> username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx
>
> Response & HTML
> -----------------------------
> Reload the page to get source for: https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pModule=bG9naW4=&pSub=bG9naW4=&pAct=cHJvY2Nlc3M=
> ```

I've tried two different code and it failed.
this is it:

```
private void login1(){
    BufferedReader in = null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.getText().toString()));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.getText().toString()));

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();            
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pModule=bG9naW4=&pSub=bG9naW4=&pAct=cHJvY2Nlc3M=");
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line + nl);
        }
        in.close();

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(buffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
privated void Login2()
{           
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;          
        String parameters = "username=" + user.getText().toString() + "&password=" + pass.getText().toString();   

        try
        {
            url = new URL("https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pModule=bG9naW4=&pSub=bG9naW4=&pAct=cHJvY2Nlc3M=");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(parameters.length()));
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();            
            String line = "";               
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }           
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txt.setText(sb.toString());        
            isr.close();
            reader.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Error
        }
}
```

do you know where's my mistake?

Thanks for your help.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send your query as a `GET`, depending on how the server is coded, it might work:

```
https://xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/index.php?pModule=bG9naW4=&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&pSub=bG9naW4=&pAct=cHJvY2Nlc3M=
```

Replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with whatever credentials you want to log on with.

Comment: I've tried it and it replied nothing. If I try it manually on web browser, it said I need to input username and password. So, I think the site isn't passing username and password via URL parameters, but via POST method. So, the above codes should be work. I think I need another argument to be passed via POST method but I don't know what.

Comment: Yes the server-side code is probably rendering the login page when it receives a GET and trying to actually login when it receives a POST. It's a common pattern

Comment: I think it's caused by https, but I tried to access https//account.google.com and it replied that I couldn't use POST method. Or is it caused by no cookies provided?